# Node.js TypeError: object is not a function. What is the issue here?

Tags: node.js

I am new to node.js and I have the following exported function

*LiveEvent.js*

```
function liveEvent(connection) { 
   this.db = connection.
}

liveEvent.prototype.someMethod = function() { } 

module.exports = liveEvent;
```

**Now in another file**

*Enduser.js*

```
var LiveEvent = require('./LiveEvent');
```

When i try to do the following i get **TypeError: object is not a function**

```
var liveEvent = new LiveEvent(connection);
```

What am i doing wrong ? Any suggestions appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the `function` keyword to create a prototype method.

```
function liveEvent(connection) { 
   this.db = connection;
}

liveEvent.prototype.someMethod = function() { } 

module.exports = liveEvent;
```